# Conditionally join a pandas DF on multiple indexes

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes of different lengths, and I need to conditionally overwrite the value from one into the other when two columns match.

```
df1.val = df2.val where df1.val == null and df1.key1 == df2.key1 and df1.key2 == df2.key2
```

`df1` and `df2` have very different sets of columns and row lengths, save for `key1`, `key2`, and `val`. The only thing that's guaranteed is that for every `(key1, key2)` in `df1`, there is exactly one `(key1, key2)` in `df2`.

So far I've been going down the path of

```
df1.loc[df1.val.isnull(), "val"] = df2.val
```

trying to set indexes to match, but I haven't got anywhere on that.

I know there's some join-ons, but I haven't made any progress on that front either. Some syntactical help would be appreciated.

Edit for data:

*DF1:*

```
First  Last   Val Random1 ...
John   Smith    4 x
Todd   Smith    5 Nan
John   Todd   Nan z
```

*DF2:*

```
First  Last   Val Random2 ...
John   Smith    7 4
Todd   Smith    6 9
John   Todd     3 3
Eric   Smith    5 2
```

*Result:*

```
First  Last   Val Random1 ...OtherDF1Cols...
John   Smith    4 x
Todd   Smith    5 Nan
John   Todd     3 z
```

Comment: Can you add some data samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your indices first, then `fillna`

```
DF1.set_index(['First', 'Last']).fillna(DF2.set_index(['First', 'Last']))

             Val
First Last      
John  Smith  4.0
Todd  Smith  5.0
John  Todd   3.0
```

Use `combine_first` to include all stuff from both dataframes

```
DF1.set_index(['First', 'Last']).combine_first(DF2.set_index(['First', 'Last']))

             Val
First Last      
Eric  Smith  5.0
John  Smith  4.0
      Todd   3.0
Todd  Smith  5.0
```

---

Or, update just `Val` column, and limit to just rows from first

```
d1 = DF1.set_index(['First', 'Last'])
d2 = DF2.set_index(['First', 'Last'])
print(d1.combine_first(d2[['Val']]).loc[d1.index].reset_index())

  First   Last  Val
0  John  Smith  4.0
1  Todd  Smith  5.0
2  John   Todd  3.0
```

---

An option using `update`

```
d1 = DF1.set_index(['First', 'Last'])
d2 = DF2.set_index(['First', 'Last'])
d1.update(d2.Val, overwrite=False)
d1.reset_index()

  First   Last  Val
0  John  Smith  4.0
1  Todd  Smith  5.0
2  John   Todd  3.0
```

Comment: I don't want to fill all null values, just the ones in the val column.

Comment: How would you approach it if you wanted to replace both null and 0 values?